# Cloud services deployment using smart contracts

Tags: cloud, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Can smart contracts launch cloud computing services like Iaas i.e  is that possible to write a deployment script for the smart contract to launch cloud services

Answer (score 0):

In a word: No.

If you *really* wanted to, you could have a smart contract that would emit some event when a given function was called. Then you could have some service listening for that event, and launching whatever you want, cloud service or any job. I can't think of a reason to use blockchain for this though : the "listener" service would be centralized, as would the cloud job you would be launching. So you may as well just make API calls directly to that, and skip the blockchain altogether.